# Benefits of a geospatial index or simple lat/long (in MongoDB and in general)

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

I want to retrieve from DB items that are 'near' a certain geographic point. Should I:

1. Use a geo-spatial index?
2. Use simple lat/longitude coordinates?

Assuming my only use-case is 'items 5 miles or less from x', #2 seems like the right choice to me, just for its simplicity.

(For example, each DB item will have 'lat: 101.12, long: 94.75', and by indexing those two I should achieve extremely simple querying on a square of 5 miles east/west and north/south. I note this 'square' is *not* an exact 5-mile-radius sphere. I also lose the ability to perform other, more powerful, queries. What I gain is a very simple scheme. My current intended DB is Mongo, but this scheme would work in any DB where I can index numeric fields (which is a major bonus itself).

So assuming simple use-case as above, are there any benefits (performance or otherwise) to using a geo-spatial index over simple lat/longitude (like performance)? Or do geo-spatial indexes only grant stronger querying abilities in terms of 'what they can do'?

Comment: Should I? Perhaps show a real scenario where you are trying to solve a problem. With example data and code that you have tried and the problem you are facing. Otherwise this is not a valid post here. People will help you with specific problems. But too broad is too broad. Present a real problem and you get an answer.

Comment: Well, yes, but in general, an R-tree (or variant thereof), will outperform an index on lat/lon by an order of magnitude. There are already many questions that deal with this question. MongoDB's 2dsphere is based on a geohash (B-tree), so the performance pick up will be less, but still preferable to separate indexes on lat and lon.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can use a rectangular boundary to filter the points. Then you can use the harvesine formula to compute the distances. A spatial index uses trees or space filling curves and can be sometimes faster. Especially with space filling curves you can do interesting queries.